# How to calculate the differential of inclusion in the case of x-axis to $\mathbb R^2$.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to understand tangent space on submanifolds and how to calculate which tangent vectors in the larger space are considered tangent space in the submanifold. I found this a very confusing topic and actually calculating the differential of the inclusion is just as confusing. So according to these notes: http://www.math.toronto.edu/mgualt/courses/18-367/docs/DiffGeomNotes-8.pdf,

we have that :
[image]

This is all understandable, but I am having trouble with even simple calculations so I want to take the easiest example possible: $\mathbb R^2$ and look at the x-axis as an embedded submanifold and calculate its tangent space. I will note that I want to avoid making any simplifications and be as rigorous as possible (so I will avoid identifying the tangent space itself with $\mathbb R^2$ so I can get a better grasp of how this works in abstract manifolds.

So now take the Euclidean 2 space $\mathbb R^2$. Now this manifold has a global chart which is $\mathbb R^2$ (Again, I am doing this because I want to be as precise and rigorous here as possible even if it seems a bit unnecessary). Now the tangent space at each point $p$ is given by the basis tangent vectors $\partial_x,\partial_y$. Now our global chart also gives us an adapted chart for the x-axis which turns it into a regular/embedded submanifold because the y-coordinate vanishes. Now since the x-axis is itself a manifold in its own right, we need a different label for the coordinates, so we can call it $x'$. Now I actually don't know if this step is necessary even if we are trying to be very rigorous and precise, so please correct me if that is the case. Now we know the x-axis is a 1-dimensional submanifold and thus its tangent space is one dimensional which has to be spanned by $\partial_x'$. Now, this is the part that I don't quite get: we know intuitively that the differential of the inclusion $di\partial_x'$ has to be equal to $\partial_x$. But for some reason, I just don't see how we can figure that out by computation.

Note: the definition of tangent vectors I am using is derivations acting on smooth functions so I would like to stick to that here. But if someone can explain why using the "curves" definition would be superior here for our purposes, that would also be great.

Comment: I strongly suspect your problem here is that you are trying to make things far more complicated than they actually are. The $x$-axis is an embedding of $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R^2$ per the map $i : t \mapsto (t,0)$. (I think it wiser to use $t$ as the coordinate on $\Bbb R$.) On $\Bbb R$ at a point $p, \partial_t|_p = \frac d{dt}|_p$, while in $\Bbb R^2$ at a point $q = (u,v), \partial_x|_q = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_q$, and similarly for $\partial_y|_q$. Thus $di|_p : a\partial_t|_p \mapsto a\partial_x|{(p,0)}$for all $a, p \in \Bbb R$. That is all there is to it.

Comment: Hi paul, thanks for the comment. So the difficulty I am having right now is that as obvious and intuitive as $\left.d i\right|_p:\left.a \partial_t\right|_p \mapsto a \partial_x \mid(p, 0)$, I actually have trouble showing that is the case through explicit computation. If we evaluate the coordinate function $x$ on the left-hand side, we should get $a$.

Comment: No you should not. The coordinate function $x$ acts on the point of the manifold, which is $p$ in $\Bbb R$, and its image $(p, 0)$ in $\Bbb R^2$, where the value of $x$ is $p$. $di|_p$ carries $T_p\Bbb R$ into $T_{(p,0)}\Bbb R^2$. Since $T_p\Bbb R$ is one-dimensional, every vector in it is a multiple of $\partial_t|_p$. So if $v\in T_p\Bbb R$, then $v = a\partial_t|_p$ for some $a$, and $di|_p(v) = a\partial_x|_{(p,0)}$